# is there any way to print to DataMax printer Through her driver - using asp.net in the client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

is there any way to print to DataMax printer Through her driver

using asp.net in the client side ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use their SDK instead. You have download that from their website

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the information of the drivers or control of which printer will the user use to print on the Client side. You can only Issue a print command in the javascript and the control will go to the Browser which will open its Print Dilogue Box. U can suggest user in your page regarding print instructions but cant do it yourself.

Following is the snippet to print the whole page

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
    function printpage() {
    window.print();
    }
//-->
</script>
```